# S3 Rest Call through Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is it possible to retrieve an excel file from S3 through rest? And if possible does anybody know how to do this through a client such as google chrome's Postman? I've tried using the ruby sdk but got fairly lost since I barely have any experience with Ruby Gems and Ruby in general.

Comment: Yes, S3 exposes RESTful API though its not as simple as your normal application. I wish I could get a postman example but I believe you should do the digging. Here're some readings: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php

Comment: If the file is public, than its a simple HTTP call :D. If not, it's still possible. But you need to make an authenticating call before. Described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html Then you can do the getObject call with the token: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Comment: But a simple hack would be using AWS CLI S3 cp  function. That can handle your credentials.